# I have a undeleteable Linux icon which leads to wsl.localhost on my windows 10 desktop

Tags: linux, windows-10, icons

So one day when I boot up my Windows 10 PC, there was a Linux icon on my desktop which leads to `wsl.localhost` in the file manager.

And like I’ve said in the title, the icon/shortcut thing can’t be moved to the recycling bin, doesn’t have a delete option and when I check its properties, it just shows it’s unavailable.
In file manager, I’ve found a Linux section and I used a **.reg** file to remove the linux section.

I’ve never installed WSL and have disabled the option already. But the shortcut/icon still is there and undeletable and still leads to `wsl.localhost` from the file manager.

How do I delete this icon? It’s not even found in the desktop folders.

Answer (score 0):

This post seems to address the same problem:
[Linux Icon on my Desktop that I can't remove (Not in File Explorer)](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/185fyx2/linux_icon_on_my_desktop_that_i_cant_remove_not/) :

> I have a Linux Icon on my Desktop that I can't remove, there is no delete option when I right click.

The user "BrainBOne" offered this fix that worked for at least one more user:

> Yes, I have found a solution.
>
> Read more here:
> https://www.brainbytez.nl/windows/windows-11-hide-remove-wsl-linux-icon-from-desktop/
>
> Short story: I added the CLSID for the Linux icon to the
> `HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel` section with the Registry Editor.
>
> ```
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
>
> "{B2B4A4D1-2754-4140-A2EB-9A76D9D7CDC6}"=dword:00000001
> ```